# C#. The same code only works on 1 label... why?

Tags: c#, winforms, datetime

I made 2 radiobuttons so the user can choose if he/she wants to view the time on a 24h format or a 12h format, this is the code I have on the timer:

```
var format = rad24h.Checked ? "HH:mm" : "hh:mm:ss tt";

        timer1.Interval = 500;

        DateTime myDateTime = DateTime.Now;

        label1.Text = string.Format("Hora actual {0}\n  ", myDateTime.ToString(format));

        lblHK.Text = string.Format("Hong Kong {0}\n  ", myDateTime.AddHours(7).ToString(format));

        lblNY.Text = string.Format("Nova Iorque {0}\n   ", myDateTime.AddHours(-5).ToString(format));

        lblUkr.Text = string.Format("Ucrânia {0}\n", myDateTime.AddHours(2).ToString(format));

        lblTay.Text = string.Format("Taymyrskiy {0}\n  ", myDateTime.AddHours(3).ToString(format));

        lblAla.Text = string.Format("  Alaska {0}\n", myDateTime.AddHours(-9).ToLongString(format));

        lblUru.Text = string.Format("Uruguay {0}\n", myDateTime.AddHours(-4).ToString(format));

        lblSyd.Text = string.Format(" Sydney {0}\n", myDateTime.AddHours(9).ToString(format));

        lblMad.Text = string.Format("Madagascar {0}\n   ", myDateTime.AddHours(2).ToString(format));
```

The only label that does work with this is the lblUkr, (fourth from top-down)...

I've checked everything on the other lines to ensure they are the same, what I'm I missing?

Also, the label does not show AM/PM... how can I do this?

**UPDATE**

Actually, I noticed something weird... the first time I tried the code I did it only on lblUkr, and it was working, then I changed the position of the radio buttons, put the 24h one on top and made it already selected, but when I debug it goes down and none is selected... I assume that somehow, when it debugs it does not update on what I am doing on the application... any ideas what could be wrong?

**UPDATE 2**

It does work now, I had to re-save the project and change some things and all and it now works, but still, there is no AM, PM text on the end of the clocks, do I need to do it myself or is there a code to it?

Comment: Could you add some more code , also the output screen? This will help to understand the problem better

Comment: Seems fine .. What does your statement *does not work* mean ?

Comment: Label works you mean shows time in correct format?

Comment: @subhen 
Actually, I noticed something weird... the first time I tried the code I did it only on lblUkr, and it was working, then I changed the position of the radio buttons, put the 24h one on top and made it already selected, but when I debug it goes down and none is selected... I assume that somehow, when it debugs it does not update on what I am doing on the application... any ideas what could be wrong?

Comment: @Madcowe: AM/PM not working would suggest that its using your 24-hour handler.  Unless your check box/radio button isn't correctly wired up, or you are accidentally using the value from the wrong control, then I'm not sure why that would happen without seeing all your code.

Comment: @merlyn thanks but now I got it working, I added a `using System.Globalization;` and also ` var format = rad24h.Checked ? "H:mm:ss" : "h:mm:ss tt";` `     lblNY.Text = string.Format("Nova Iorque\n{0}", myDateTime.AddHours(-5).ToString(format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's working fine for me.  Not sure what the problem is.

**Make sure you actually start your timer, and that you've bound your code to run on the `Tick` event...**

To check that it was "working fine", I converted your sample to look like this:

```
var format = false ? "HH:mm" : "hh:mm:ss tt";
DateTime myDateTime = DateTime.Now;
Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Hora actual {0}\n  ", myDateTime.ToString(format)));
Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Hong Kong {0}\n  ", myDateTime.AddHours(7).ToString(format)));
Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Nova Iorque {0}\n   ", myDateTime.AddHours(-5).ToString(format)));
Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Ucrânia {0}\n", myDateTime.AddHours(2).ToString(format)));
Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Taymyrskiy {0}\n  ", myDateTime.AddHours(3).ToString(format)));
Console.WriteLine(string.Format("  Alaska {0}\n", myDateTime.AddHours(-9).ToString(format)));
Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Uruguay {0}\n", myDateTime.AddHours(-4).ToString(format)));
Console.WriteLine(string.Format(" Sydney {0}\n", myDateTime.AddHours(9).ToString(format)));
Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Madagascar {0}\n   ", myDateTime.AddHours(2).ToString(format)));
```

When you change `var format = false ...` to `var format = true ...`, then it switches from a 12 hour clock to a 24 hour clock.  This is what you described, so that code is fine.

Maybe you should set a break point and check variables/see how many times your code gets called via the debugger...

Comment: actually, I noticed something weird... the first time I tried the code I did it only on lblUkr, and it was working, then I changed the position of the radio buttons, put the 24h one on top and made it already selected, but when I debug it goes down and none is selected...

I assume that somehow, when it debugs it does not update on what I am doing on the application... any ideas what could be wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The code you posted should work. Try calling `.Invalidate()` or `.Refresh()` for each of the labels to make sure they are redrawn. Also, I assume you are using a `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` so there is no cross-thread control access, right?

Answer (score 1):

```
DateTime date1; 
date1 = new DateTime(2008, 1, 1, 18, 9, 1);
Console.WriteLine(date1.ToString("hh:mm:ss tt", 
                  CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
// Displays 06:09:01 PM
```

and also you can use cultures for your countries alike

```
Console.WriteLine(date1.ToString("hh:mm:ss tt", 
                  CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("hu-HU")));
// Displays 06:09:01 du.
```

-- from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)

So you are using correct format, but try to make it alike this in OOP style :)

Answer (score 0):

Check the format, the H is for 24 hour format, the h is for 12 hours.

and 'tt' for AM or PM.

Comment: i think you are mistaken .. check it out yourself ! ! !

Comment: So, you've just confirmed that Madcowe is using the correct format :)